# getting resource as console output

Tags: javascript, object

When I `console.log` some variable `myVar`, I get this

```
Resource {task: Object, $promise: Object, $resolved: true, $get: function, $save: function…}
```

But if I `console.log` `myVar.task`, I get `undefined`. How can I fetch the `task` object data ?

Comment: `console.log` with objects is asynchronous in showing their properties. The `task` property gets populated later. For the sport - try `setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Task: ", myBar.task); },2000)`

Comment: great ! could you set it as a response, it is very interesting !

Comment: I expected other people to answer but apparently that wasn't the case, done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log` with objects is asynchronous in showing their properties.

The `task` property of the resource objectsgets populated later.

For the sport - try `setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Task: ", myBar.task); },2000)` (updated, it indeed worked).

This is rather surprising - but has obvious speed gains, you don't want your log to be too expensive and hang the actual code.